# Display off animation in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, authentication, animation

Does anyone know how to change the default "fading out" animation when you put the computer to sleep or make the displays power down via a command line?

I was looking for a CRT-style animation as used in [Android gingerbread](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i58asXnlGfM).

The operating system is *Windows 7 x64 (pro edition)*.

<sup>Also - I do understand it's unsupported and probably requires some DLL hacking (like in case of changing login screen mechanics).

Just wondering if anyone looked for it / tried it.</sup>

Comment: Any solution is almost certainly unsupported, and can cause problems.

Comment: It would help to identify what operating system you are using, as well as your desktop environment if your operating system offers more than one.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in the basic info :> The OS is 64 bit Windows 7 professional.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If it requires you digging into the internals of your system and coming up with a programatic solution, you're most likely want this question to be on Stack Overflow. Please wait and don't open yet another question there, this will happen automatically for you and you will get a message...

Comment: Sounds like a cool weekend project.  It's Monday here, but i'll keep it in mind.  Wanna start a bounty? :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not fake it? Take a screenshot, do the animation full screen, and once the screen goes black initiate the sleep/power down. Fading out from an already black screen is pretty hard to see, and might look impressive enough, depending on your needs.